# Sorting data list according to an external list

Tags: r, sorting, web-scraping

I have a data frame with 81 objects and 12 variables, including an ID for each object.
Further, I have a sorted(!) list of ID's.

Now, I want to sort my data frame after this specific list.

Can anyone make a simple example for that case?

I am a newbie, trying to learn.

Thanks in advance!

Quick example of my case:

```
                         ID     City     NR1       NR2
         Dataframe1 = "11000", Berlin, (123,2), (532,1)
                      "02401", Hamburg, (435,2), (352,1)
                      "83329", München, (124,3), (125,2)
        

         ID = list("02401", "83329", "11000")
```

Now, I want Dataframe1 to be sorted after the ID from the list.

Comment: It would be easier to help you If you posted the data from the data frame and the list. Try posting dput(your_data_frame) and dput(your_list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can arrange your dataframe using `arrange()`.

An example:
The iris dataset, as is:

```
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

```
creating an external vector:

index<-sample(1:150)
```

Then you can sort your dataframe with that external vector:

```
head(arrange(iris, index))

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1          6.4         2.7          5.3         1.9  virginica
2          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2     setosa
3          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
4          6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor
5          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica
6          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
```

To arrange by a specific external vector that matches one of the variables, you can use `match()`

```
iris2<-head(iris)%>%mutate(ID=sample(1:150, 6))

> iris2
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species ID
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 29
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 61
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 69
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 89
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 59
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 84
```

```
external_vector<-c(69,59,84,29,61,89)
```

arrange with `match()`:

```
iris2[match(external_vector, iris2$ID),]

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species ID
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 69
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 59
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 84
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 29
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 61
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 89
```

Comment: It is unfortunately not helping. My goal is not to sort it numerically ascending like an index (1,2,3,4,5). I have a list of ID'S like  ("11000", "04234", "81232"...) and I need my data frame, containing the IDs but it in an unsorted way, in exactly that specific order. Hope u got it.. thank you for helping